# Should @vue/composition-api be added in devDepencies

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-composition-api

Should I install `@vue/composition-api` in `package.json` dependencies rather than in devDependencies?

I see on [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/composition-api) that it is in dependencies

Comment: The difference between deps and devdeps applies to the packages, there's only semantic difference in the project itself. If a dep is imported in the app, it belongs to deps. If it's used to build it, it belongs to devdeps.

Answer (score 0):

Following the logic of vue-property-decorator or vue-class-component, this are installed as dependencies.

I would say this is actual dependency for your project once is build, so it is not a dev dependency.

Comment: I tried to put it in the devDependencies and build the project with --env=production, the project was working. That is why I wonder why it should be in dependencies?(even if for me it makes more sense to put it in dependencies)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).